# Adding custom form into Devise edit page Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am having a problem to add custom form into Devise `edit` page. Currently, I have two models `User` and `UserAddress`. I splitted `edit` page on multiple pages, here are my routes:

```
devise_for :users, path: "user", path_names: {sing_in: "sign_in", sing_out: "sign_out", sing_up: "sign_up", edit: "edit"}, :controllers => { :registrations => :registrations }
devise_scope :user do
  match 'user/edit' => 'registrations#edit', via: :get, :as => :user_basic
  match 'user/edit/addresses' => 'registrations#addresses', via: :get, :as => :user_addresses
  ...
  resources :user_addresses, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
resources :users, path: "user", only: [:show]
```

I created `User Addresses` controller to handle `create` and `destroy` actions:

```
class UserAddressesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @User = User.find(params[:user_id])
    if params[:addresses]
      params[:addresses].each do |address|
        @User.address.create(address: address)
      end
      @addresses = @User.addresses
      redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referer, notice: "Success")
    end
  end

  def destoy
    @address = Address.find(params[:id])
    @User = @address.user

    @address.destroy
    @addresses = Address.where(user_id: @user.id)

    respond_to :js
  end
end
```

And now I want to add the ability to add new addresses from Devise `edit` page (I will use `ajax` lately to update the records under the form), like this (`haml`):

```
= form_for user_addresses_path, url: user_addresses_path(current_user), method: 'post', :html => { class: "form", :multipart => true } do |f|
  = f.text_field :name
  = f.text_field :address
  = f.submit
```

When I click `submit`, I am getting the following error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/user/edit/addresses.1"
```

I think that I need to move `resources :user_addresses, only: [:create, :destroy]` out of the `devise_scope`, however I don't want to change the `url` (www.url.com/user/edit/addresses). What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to add custom forms into Devise? Thank you very much for your help and time.

**UPDATE:**

`UserAddress` model:

```
class UserAddress < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'user_id'

  # Geocoder
  geocoded_by :address
  after_validation :geocode, :if => lambda{ |obj| obj.address_changed? }  
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here your route user/edit/address is being generate from the match and is written via get method so you need to change it with

```
match 'user/edit/addresses' => 'registrations#addresses', via: :post, :as => :user_addresses
```

and in the form url path helper you are passing current user as a parameter while it does not exist in your route so form should get replace with

```
= form_for user_addresses_path, url: user_addresses_path, method: 'post', :html => { class: "form", :multipart => true } do |f|
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond. It does work, however it won't create a new `address` record. However, seems like a good approach. Thanks.